# Displayed equation inside inline enumeration

Tags: enumitem, displaystyle

I want a proof having an enumerate environment that is inline. An equation is given in the proof. I cannot write that equation as displayed (I get an error).

*How can I make the equation displayed while keeping the inline enumerate environment?* MWE below. (Can someone else help me by adding an image of the output, please?)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\normalfont{\bfseries (\alph{enumi})}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. 

\begin{theorem}
Here is a theorem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Here is some text. Here is an equation: $a = b$. 
\item How do I make that equation displayed?
\end{enumerate*}
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `resume` option of enumitem: you interrupt the enumeration, insert the display, then resume the enumeration. But are you sure you want an inline enumeration?

*Note:* You can set the values of list parameters with the `\setlist` command from `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\normalfont\bfseries (\alph*)}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.

\begin{theorem}
  Here is a theorem.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First.
    \item Second.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate*}
    \item Here is some text. Here is an equation:\end{enumerate*}
    \[ a = b. \]
    \begin{enumerate*}[resume]
      \item How do I make that equation displayed?
      \item This way, for instance. %
    \end{enumerate*}
    \end{proof}
    \bigskip
    \begin{proof}
      \begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt]
        \item Here is some text. Here is an equation:
              \[ a = b. \]
        \item How do I make that equation displayed?
        \item This way, for instance.
      \end{enumerate} \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, Bernard! I do think that the majority of the time, the inline enumeration would be ugly. But inline enumeration does seem nicer (to me) when the parts of a proof are quite short.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by the `inline` option to [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). One way around this is to define a "fake" equation environment, that centers some text on a line with `\displaystyle` in force. Doing this produces:
[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\normalfont{\bfseries (\alph{enumi})}}

\newenvironment{myequation}% fake "displaystyle" environment
   {\newline\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\hbox to \textwidth\bgroup\hss$\displaystyle}
   {$\hss\egroup\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.

\begin{theorem}
Here is a theorem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Here is some text. Here is an equation:
\begin{myequation}
 a = b.
\end{myequation}
\item How do I make that equation displayed?
\end{enumerate*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Let me know if you'd like to also have numbered equations and I'll modify so taht there is a `myequation*` variant with no equation numbers and a `myequation` with equation numbers.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some vertical spacing in your environment (e.g. \above/belowdisplayshortskip)?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, you're right. I"ll add this. Thanks!